# Turn off Verbose in [just-audio] Flutter Plugin?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, just-audio

I'm using Flutter's Just-Audio plugin to play audio from the web.

https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio

https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio

At the moment I get lots of printouts in the run console of Android Studio. It's making development really difficult as I have to scroll through pages and pages to find the info I need. Any idea how to shut it off? I've looked for the word "verbose" and "VERBOSE". I've disabled any "print()" in the code. But still, I'm getting pages and pages of text.

Comment: There is no option for the log level, but you can make a feature request on the GitHub page if you would like it.

Comment: Yeah this is very much needed... because its a bit too much, like really too much.